# subscribers in wordpress users and in external platform

Tags: wordpress, subscription, mailing-list

is it possible for a wordpress subscription form to add subscribers in the wordpress user list and, at the same time, in a list on an external platform, such as mailchimp or activecampaign?

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do it. However, you need to take into consideration the GDPR laws (and similar around the world). **It is illegal to collect user data without consent.**

In WordPress you need to use `user_register` hook - which will fire right after user registers. The hook passes user ID and from there you can get the email address and subscribe the user to a mailing list via API call.

```
add_action('user_register','my_function');

function my_function($user_id){
  //do your stuff
}
```

Reference for MailChimp API: https://mailchimp.com/developer/guides/create-your-first-audience/

Comment: An upvote for the GDPR information. Nice succinct answer.